Not getting coinbase hot wallet transfer signatures when using getSignatureForAddress
I'm trying to track all deposits / transfers done on a phantom wallet. I'm able to get mostly all the signatures when using getSignatureForAddress on a wallet using Helius' solana RPC, but the only thing that it's not getting are signatures from coinbase hot wallet transfers.
